# dynamically change ListView size and load images

Tags: java, android

i want to create a ListView with images and text in every row that change his size dynamically (for example, at start the listView will show nothing and then, i will can add entries to the listView), also i want that the listView will can load List of Bitmap images and not images from drawable.

i created this code, however the code only load images from drawable and created once (mean that i cant change the list dynamically  - adding or remove listView entries)

```
String[] text = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
       "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

     int[] image = { R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo,
       R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo,
       R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo, R.drawable.logo };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, listImages));
          edittext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

          edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
          {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
           {

           }

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
            int count, int after)
           {

           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
            int before, int count)
           {

            textlength = edittext.getText().length();
            text_sort.clear();
            image_sort.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
            {
             if (textlength <= text[i].length())
             {
              if (edittext.getText().toString().
           equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
              {
               text_sort.add(text[i]);
              // image_sort.add(image[i]);
              }
             }
            }

            lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter
             (text_sort, image_sort));

           }
          });
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this implementation of listview  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/Demonstratestheusingalistviewintranscriptmode.htm

Check this tutorial for using customizing list view item http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/

Eidt : 
Use this adapter class:

```
  class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
      public static  ArrayList text_array = new ArrayList();
      public static  ArrayList image_array = new ArrayList();
      public int getCount(){
           return text_array..size();
      }
      public long getItemId(int position){
           return position;
      }
      public String getItem(int position){
           return null;
      }
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflate = getLayoutInflater();
        View v = inflate.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

         if(listImages.get(position) != null) {
                     image.setImageBitmap(image_array.get(position));
                     image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          } else {
                     image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     image.setImageBitmap(null);
                      image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
     return v;

    }
     public void addObject(String text, Bitmap bitmap) {
    text_array.add(text);
        image_array.add(bitmap);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
     } 
}
```

call addObject function from your activity class to add new item in list view

Comment: hi, thanks for answer, however this link didnt help me, there is no example of how dynamically adding or removing items from listView and how to load list of Bitmap images to listview...any further help? thanks

Comment: its and example from android sample you can see it result in ApiDemo app and it is for dynamic list view. For using image in listview you have to extend BaseAdapter/ArrayAdapter class for your list view

Comment: i updated my code (the getView func) and i have a problem (post logcat too)